# Upload .csv to AzureSQL using terminal

Tags: macos, azure-sql-database, rodbc

I have a .csv that my R code updates daily. I want this .csv to be present in the azureSQL, thus I want to write a script which does this

I tired to do the same using R (ODBC) but this was too slow. I thought of using terminal for this because R can also do this using system().

I know something called BCP, but I can't figure out how to do this in Mac despite this link (http://blog.nguyenvq.com/blog/2010/04/15/accessing-ms-sql-server-from-command-line-in-mac-os-x-and-linuxunix/)

P.S: I have ODBC link from the Azure SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are follow-up posts to the one you pointed above which should help you connect from your Mac: 
http://blog.nguyenvq.com/blog/2010/05/16/freetds-unixodbc-rodbc-r/ 
http://blog.nguyenvq.com/blog/2013/04/06/guide-to-accessing-ms-sql-server-and-mysql-server-on-mac-os-x/

```
library(RODBC)

ch1 <- odbcConnect(dsn="sqlserver01", uid="username", pwd="password")<br>
odbcQuery(ch1, "select name from master..sysdatabases") <br>
odbcFetchRows(ch1)
```

That said, if you could also please share your script I could help figure out why it is running slowly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually use library(RSQLServer) to directly upload data directly to azuresql. Thanks a lot for the answer!